# Hp 4530s 32-bit to 64-bit

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, upgrade, 32-bit, oem

I have a Hp 4530s.

It came with a 32-bit oem key Windows 7.
I know my computer is compatible with 64-bit, if I use the Iso from microsoft to install a 64-bit version.

Will my oem key work?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the license key with either a 32 bit or 64 bit Windows 7 installation (though not both at the same time, of course).

If HP did not provide you with a 64 bit installation, you can install from a retail Windows 7 DVD image. As long as you are installing the same version of Windows 7 (e.g Home Premium / Professional), your OEM key (printed on the Certificate of Authenticity attached to your computer) should work (something that is not necessarily true of older versions of Windows).

Comment: Is it possible to check if a key will work? I don't really want to install it and find it doesnt?

Comment: Somewhere on your computer, you should find a COA sticker with a license key. If it is an authentic COA it should have some shiny "holographic" foil. The key printed on the COA will work for the Windows edition specified on the sticker, in either 64 or 32 bit versions (the same key works for either one).

Comment: One thing to note is the version of windows 7 you have. Your activation key will not work on pro if its a home key. SORRY just noticed you specified that lol.

Comment: Hmm I gathered that much, when it's finished downloading I'll find the sticker

Comment: If the sticker came on the system and the MOBO hasn't been changed it WILL work. Worst case you will have to call the 1-800 number and activate over the phone.

Answer (score -1):

It should, If HP had provided you with a genuine copy of Windows 7.

You can get more information about this from Microsoft's website by clicking [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/32-bit-and-64-bit-windows#1TC=windows-7).

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Is it possible to check if a key will work?
I don't really want to install it and find it doesnt?

Comment: Of course it is. You can check the authenticity of your key from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/genuine/validate/). :)

Comment: @Mohi That link is for validating the Windows installation of the computer that visits it. It does *not* tell you if a particular key will work to register a particular version of Windows.

Comment: Yeah I used it, but it only said it was genuine

Comment: @Izam What's the diffenrce? A key always work on both architecture just not at the same time. He has to remove the 32bit version first and install the same edition of Windows 7 with 64bit architecture. I thought you had cleared it enough already. The only problem left was to figure out the validity of the key. Some OEMs or their retailers use pirated/cracked versions of Windows and provide a fake key just to satisfy the customer. I gave the validation link to check the genuineness of it so he wouldn't have any problem regarding key during the installation of 64bit version of the same edition.